# Road not detected in HERE Maps Javascript API

Tags: javascript, routes, here-api, here-maps-rest

Recently I've been trying to make some routes through a specific road in Spain (screenshot and link to the route below), and although I've been able to guide it through it via a web app, it's been impossible for me to do the same using the Javascript API.
When I try to place a waypoint in the desired road, I get this error message

**NoRouteFound**:

```
{
    "_type":"ns2:RoutingServiceErrorType",
    "type":"ApplicationError",
    "subtype":"NoRouteFound",
    "details":"Error is NGEO_ERROR_GRAPH_DISCONNECTED_CHECK_OPTIONS","additionalData":[{"key":"error_code","value":"NGEO_ERROR_GRAPH_DISCONNECTED_CHECK_OPTIONS"}],
    "metaInfo":
    {
        "timestamp":"2021-02-04T14:43:16Z",
        "mapVersion":"8.30.117.150",
        "moduleVersion":"7.2.202105-1486",
        "interfaceVersion":"2.6.76",
        "availableMapVersion":["8.30.117.150"]
    }
}
```

I've tried to remove route restrictions as well but no luck. Just hoping that someone has encountered the same problem

ROUTE VIA HERE WEB APP [here](https://wego.here.com/directions/mix/Amoroto:loc-dmVyc2lvbj0xO3RpdGxlPUFtb3JvdG87bGFuZz1lcztsYXQ9NDMuMzI2Mjc7bG9uPS0yLjUxMzU1O2NpdHk9QW1vcm90bztwb3N0YWxDb2RlPTQ4Mjg5O2NvdW50cnk9RVNQO3N0YXRlPVBhJUMzJUFEcytWYXNjbztjb3VudHk9Vml6Y2F5YTtjYXRlZ29yeUlkPWNpdHktdG93bi12aWxsYWdlO3NvdXJjZVN5c3RlbT1pbnRlcm5hbDtwZHNDYXRlZ29yeUlkPTkwMC05MTAwLTAwMDA/N-I,-20213-Idiazabal-Guip%C3%BAzcoa,-Espa%C3%B1a:42.98539,-2.23771/Pamplona,-Espa%C3%B1a:loc-dmVyc2lvbj0xO3RpdGxlPVBhbXBsb25hO2xhbmc9ZXM7bGF0PTQyLjgxMjc5O2xvbj0tMS42NDMzMjtjaXR5PVBhbXBsb25hO2NvdW50cnk9RVNQO3N0YXRlPUNvbXVuaWRhZCtGb3JhbCtkZStOYXZhcnJhO2NvdW50eT1OYXZhcnJhO2NhdGVnb3J5SWQ9Y2l0eS10b3duLXZpbGxhZ2U7c291cmNlU3lzdGVtPWludGVybmFsO3Bkc0NhdGVnb3J5SWQ9OTAwLTkxMDAtMDAwMA?map=42.92641,-3.11843,9,normal&msg=N-I%20Idiazabal%20(Guip%C3%BAzcoa))

Comment: Welcome on S.O.! Can you add the routing request code that you tried, and which resulted to a _NoRouteFound_ response?

Comment: Hello Micheal, thank you very much for answering, this is the request. https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?&waypoint0=geo!43.33631,-2.4979&waypoint1=geo!42.9547,-2.2334&waypoint2=geo!42.837521,-1.682764&waypoint3=geo!42.765557,-1.633923&waypoint4=geo!42.742708,-1.633068&waypoint5=geo!42.735450,-1.633920&mode=fastest%3Btruck%3Btollroad:-3&routeattributes=all,-shape&maneuverattributes=all,-shape&linkattributes=all&language=es_es&apiKey=__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your [custom request](https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?&waypoint0=geo!43.33631,-2.4979&waypoint1=geo!42.9547,-2.2334&waypoint2=geo!42.837521,-1.682764&waypoint3=geo!42.765557,-1.633923&waypoint4=geo!42.742708,-1.633068&waypoint5=geo!42.735450,-1.633920&mode=fastest%3Btruck%3Btollroad:-3&routeattributes=all,-shape&maneuverattributes=all,-shape&linkattributes=all&language=es_es&apiKey=__) you have set up the transportation mode on `fastest;truck;tollroad:-3`, which means that you are looking for a route that can be used by *trucks*.

Meanwhile, the HERE WeGo example you linked is calculating a route for *cars*.
If we switch from `mode=fastest;truck;tollroad:-3` to `mode=fastest;car;tollroad:-3`, and leave all other parameters untouched, we can find a route going through those waypoints:

**Response**

```json
{
  "response": {
    "metaInfo": {
      "timestamp": "2021-02-08T15:08:38Z",
      "mapVersion": "8.30.117.151",
      "moduleVersion": "7.2.202105-8389",
      "interfaceVersion": "2.6.76",
      "availableMapVersion": [
        "8.30.117.151"
      ]
    },
    "route": [
      {
        "routeId": "ABUBCAAAAB4AAAB1AAAAlwAAANUBAAB42mO4ysjAxMYABDmulnW5ShfjGKCgT_6tKCODkzXD__8QgQ_7GZAAF4g45XH-JRMDS05mncyqbrjOWfNfiNYxOFng06ka_ESOkaF55dk6ndAyuM7N8c9FhTmcbPDpXFCY-JaRYXXvtboM60y4zq3zn4nmsuLXKbYwxwpo59ZrdROFUhE645-JvmDBr7O62z2VkeE80M6gA8kInfLPRDcw4tcp7Tx_OyOIwcgAphjYGHABw3UrapWYGBgMQBx-A0YFBgeGBwwMPAwMcxgUQDo5FLQYWRyC2gxUgLwvDDwODPxgjQkMzo4tfy4vvMEYkMCgwMVYI3aQEQBgWFlRrc9XUA",
        "waypoint": [
          {
            "linkId": "-1238197473",
            "mappedPosition": {
              "latitude": 43.3362329,
              "longitude": -2.4982456
            },
            "originalPosition": {
              "latitude": 43.33631,
              "longitude": -2.4979
            },
            "type": "stopOver",
            "spot": 0.3538462,
            "sideOfStreet": "left",
            "mappedRoadName": "Barrio Urrutia",
            "label": "Barrio Urrutia - BI-2405",
            "shapeIndex": 0,
            "source": "user"
          },
          {
            "linkId": "+724111030",
            "mappedPosition": {
              "latitude": 42.9544249,
              "longitude": -2.2336662
            },
            "originalPosition": {
              "latitude": 42.9547,
              "longitude": -2.2334
            },
            "type": "stopOver",
            "spot": 0.0839161,
            "sideOfStreet": "right",
            "mappedRoadName": "",
            "label": "N-I",
            "shapeIndex": 2413,
            "source": "user"
          },
          {
            "linkId": "-785506068",
            "mappedPosition": {
              "latitude": 42.8375127,
              "longitude": -1.6827625
            },
            "originalPosition": {
              "latitude": 42.8375209,
              "longitude": -1.682764
            },
            "type": "stopOver",
            "spot": 0.325,
            "sideOfStreet": "right",
            "mappedRoadName": "Calle E",
            "label": "Calle E",
            "shapeIndex": 3564,
            "source": "user"
          },
          {
            "linkId": "+784694977",
            "mappedPosition": {
              "latitude": 42.7655521,
              "longitude": -1.6340184
            },
            "originalPosition": {
              "latitude": 42.7655569,
              "longitude": -1.633923
            },
            "type": "stopOver",
            "spot": 0.6483516,
            "sideOfStreet": "right",
            "mappedRoadName": "Calle A",
            "label": "Calle A",
            "shapeIndex": 3912,
            "source": "user"
          },
          {
            "linkId": "+1167198260",
            "mappedPosition": {
              "latitude": 42.7426922,
              "longitude": -1.6330802
            },
            "originalPosition": {
              "latitude": 42.742708,
              "longitude": -1.6330681
            },
            "type": "stopOver",
            "spot": 0.3364486,
            "sideOfStreet": "neither",
            "mappedRoadName": "Carretera Salinas",
            "label": "Carretera Salinas",
            "shapeIndex": 4006,
            "source": "user"
          },
          {
            "linkId": "+1171177552",
            "mappedPosition": {
              "latitude": 42.7354551,
              "longitude": -1.633918
            },
            "originalPosition": {
              "latitude": 42.73545,
              "longitude": -1.63392
            },
            "type": "stopOver",
            "spot": 0.2121212,
            "sideOfStreet": "neither",
            "mappedRoadName": "Polígono Industrial Morea Norte",
            "label": "Polígono Industrial Morea Norte",
            "shapeIndex": 4025,
            "source": "user"
          }
        ],
        "mode": {
          "type": "fastest",
          "transportModes": [
            "car"
          ],
          "trafficMode": "disabled",
          "feature": [
            {
              "value": "tollroad",
              "weight": [
                "Byte",
                -3
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "boundingBox": {
          "topLeft": {
            "latitude": 43.3362329,
            "longitude": -2.5007308
          },
          "bottomRight": {
            "latitude": 42.7354002,
            "longitude": -1.6270387
          }
        },
        "leg": [
          {
            "start": {
              "linkId": "-1238197473",
              "mappedPosition": {
                "latitude": 43.3362329,
                "longitude": -2.4982456
              },
              "originalPosition": {
                "latitude": 43.33631,
                "longitude": -2.4979
              },
              "type": "stopOver",
              "spot": 0.3538462,
              "sideOfStreet": "left",
              "mappedRoadName": "Barrio Urrutia",
              "label": "Barrio Urrutia - BI-2405",
              "shapeIndex": 0,
              "source": "user"
            },
            "end": {
              "linkId": "+724111030",
              "mappedPosition": {
                "latitude": 42.9544249,
                "longitude": -2.2336662
              },
              "originalPosition": {
                "latitude": 42.9547,
                "longitude": -2.2334
              },
              "type": "stopOver",
              "spot": 0.0839161,
              "sideOfStreet": "right",
              "mappedRoadName": "",
              "label": "N-I",
              "shapeIndex": 2413,
              "source": "user"
            },
            "length": 79900,
            "travelTime": 5026,
            "maneuver": [
              {
                "position": {
                  "latitude": 43.3362329,
                  "longitude": -2.4982456
                },
                "instruction": "Diríjase al <span class=\"heading\">sur</span> por <span class=\"street\">Barrio Urrutia</span> <span class=\"number\">(BI-2405)</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Siga durante <span class=\"length\">170 m</span>.</span>",
                "travelTime": 10,
                "length": 170,
                "firstPoint": 0,
                "lastPoint": 8,
                "note": [],
                "nextManeuver": "M2",
                "toLink": "-1238197473",
                "boundingBox": {
                  "topLeft": {
                    "latitude": 43.3362329,
                    "longitude": -2.4984133
                  },
                  "bottomRight": {
                    "latitude": 43.3347344,
                    "longitude": -2.4981666
                  }
                },
                "shapeQuality": "exact",
                "direction": "forward",
                "action": "depart",
                "roadName": "",
                "nextRoadName": "Barrio Urrutia",
                "roadNumber": "",
                "nextRoadNumber": "BI-2405",
                "trafficTime": 10,
                "baseTime": 10,
                "roadShield": {
                  "region": "ESP",
                  "category": "3",
                  "label": "BI-2405"
                },
                "startAngle": 163,
                "id": "M1",
                "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
              },
              {
                "position": {
                  "latitude": 43.3347344,
                  "longitude": -2.4983704
                },
                "instruction": "Continúe por <span class=\"number\">BI-2405</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Siga durante <span class=\"length\">1.3 km</span>.</span>",
                "travelTime": 76,
                "length": 1298,
                "firstPoint": 8,
                "lastPoint": 42,
                "note": [],
                "nextManeuver": "M3",
                "toLink": "-1004767700",
                "boundingBox": {
                  "topLeft": {
                    "latitude": 43.3347344,
                    "longitude": -2.4983704
                  },
                  "bottomRight": {
                    "latitude": 43.3243382,
                    "longitude": -2.4930918
                  }
                },
                "shapeQuality": "exact",
                "direction": "forward",
                "action": "continue",
                "roadName": "Barrio Urrutia",
                "nextRoadName": "",
                "roadNumber": "BI-2405",
                "nextRoadNumber": "BI-2405",
                "trafficTime": 76,
                "baseTime": 76,
                "roadShield": {
                  "region": "ESP",
                  "category": "3",
                  "label": "BI-2405"
                },
                "startAngle": 171,
                "id": "M2",
                "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
              },
              {
                "position": {
                  "latitude": 43.3243382,
                  "longitude": -2.4930918
                },
                "instruction": "Continúe por <span class=\"next-street\">Atxurra</span> <span class=\"number\">(BI-2405)</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Siga durante <span class=\"length\">64 m</span>.</span>",
                "travelTime": 3,
                "length": 64,
                "firstPoint": 42,
                "lastPoint": 43,
                "note": [],
                "nextManeuver": "M4",
                "toLink": "-799933634",
                "boundingBox": {
                  "topLeft": {
                    "latitude": 43.3243382,
                    "longitude": -2.4930918
                  },
                  "bottomRight": {
                    "latitude": 43.3238447,
                    "longitude": -2.4926949
                  }
                },
                "shapeQuality": "exact",
                "direction": "forward",
                "action": "continue",
                "roadName": "",
                "nextRoadName": "Atxurra",
                "roadNumber": "BI-2405",
                "nextRoadNumber": "BI-2405",
                "trafficTime": 3,
                "baseTime": 3,
                "roadShield": {
                  "region": "ESP",
                  "category": "3",
                  "label": "BI-2405"
                },
                "startAngle": 149,
                "id": "M3",
                "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
              },
              {
                "position": {
                  "latitude": 43.3238447,
                  "longitude": -2.4926949
                },
                "instruction": "Continúe por <span class=\"number\">BI-2405</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Siga durante <span class=\"length\">4.6 km</span>.</span>",
                "travelTime": 315,
                "length": 4571,
                "firstPoint": 43,
                "lastPoint": 223,
                "note": [],
                "nextManeuver": "M5",
                "toLink": "-909177678",
                "boundingBox": {
                  "topLeft": {
                    "latitude": 43.3238447,
                    "longitude": -2.4926949
                  },
                  "bottomRight": {
                    "latitude": 43.3015716,
                    "longitude": -2.4772775
                  }
                },
                "shapeQuality": "exact",
                "direction": "forward",
                "action": "continue",
                "roadName": "Atxurra",
                "nextRoadName": "",
                "roadNumber": "BI-2405",
                "nextRoadNumber": "BI-2405",
                "trafficTime": 315,
                "baseTime": 315,
                "roadShield": {
                  "region": "ESP",
                  "category": "3",
                  "label": "BI-2405"
                },
                "startAngle": 149,
                "id": "M4",
                "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
              },
              {
                "position": {
                  "latitude": 43.3015716,
                  "longitude": -2.4783933
                },
                "instruction": "Continúe por <span class=\"next-street\">Barrio Ubilla Urberuaga</span> <span class=\"number\">(BI-2405)</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Siga durante <span class=\"length\">763 m</span>.</span>",
                "travelTime": 64,
                "length": 763,
                "firstPoint": 223,
                "lastPoint": 252,
                "note": [],
                "nextManeuver": "M6",
                "toLink": "-1238195842",
                "boundingBox": {
                  "topLeft": {
                    "latitude": 43.3015716,
                    "longitude": -2.4797666
                  },
                  "bottomRight": {
                    "latitude": 43.2969904,
                    "longitude": -2.4754214
                  }
                },
                "shapeQuality": "exact",
                "direction": "forward",
                "action": "continue",
                "roadName": "",
                "nextRoadName": "Barrio Ubilla Urberuaga",
                "roadNumber": "BI-2405",
                "nextRoadNumber": "BI-2405",
                "trafficTime": 64,
                "baseTime": 64,
                "roadShield": {
                  "region": "ESP",
                  "category": "3",
                  "label": "BI-2405"
                },
                "startAngle": 185,
                "id": "M5",
                "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
              },
              {
                "position": {
                  "latitude": 43.2969904,
                  "longitude": -2.4754214
                },
                "instruction": "Gire a la <span class=\"direction\">derecha</span> en <span class=\"next-street\">Barrio Ubilla Urberuaga</span> <span class=\"number\">(BI-633)</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Siga durante <span class=\"length\">4.0 km</span>.</span>",
                "travelTime": 291,
                "length": 3994,
                "firstPoint": 252,
                "lastPoint": 371,
                "note": [],
                "nextManeuver": "M7",
                "toLink": "-1218484943",
                "boundingBox": {
                  "topLeft": {
                    "latitude": 43.2969904,
                    "longitude": -2.4975228
                  },
                  "bottomRight": {
                    "latitude": 43.27299,
                    "longitude": -2.4754214
                  }
                },
                "shapeQuality": "exact",
                "direction": "right",
                "action": "rightTurn",
                "roadName": "Barrio Ubilla Urberuaga",
                "nextRoadName": "Barrio Ubilla Urberuaga",
                "roadNumber": "BI-2405",
                "nextRoadNumber": "BI-633",
                "trafficTime": 324,
                "baseTime": 291,
                "roadShield": {
                  "region": "ESP",
                  "category": "2",
                  "label": "BI-633"
                },
                "startAngle": 118,
                "id": "M6",
                "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
              },
              {
                "position": {
                  "latitude": 43.27299,
                  "longitude": -2.4975228
                },
                "instruction": "Gire a la <span class=\"direction\">izquierda</span> en dirección a <span class=\"sign\">Calle Beko-Benta</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Siga durante <span class=\"length\">20 m</span>.</span>",
                "travelTime": 5,
                "length": 20,
                "firstPoint": 371,
                "lastPoint": 373,
                "note": [],
                "nextManeuver": "M8",
                "toLink": "-77389318",
                "boundingBox": {
                  "topLeft": {
                    "latitude": 43.27299,
                    "longitude": -2.4975228
                  },
                  "bottomRight": {
                    "latitude": 43.2728291,
                    "longitude": -2.4974155
                  }
                },
                "shapeQuality": "exact",
                "direction": "left",
                "action": "leftTurn",
                "roadName": "",
                "nextRoadName": "",
                "roadNumber": "BI-633",
                "nextRoadNumber": "",
                "trafficTime": 5,
                "baseTime": 5,
                "startAngle": 203,
                "id": "M7",
                "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
              },
              {
                "position": {
                  "latitude": 43.2728291,
                  "longitude": -2.4974155
                },
                
// REDACTED FOR BREVITY
// REDACTED FOR BREVITY
// REDACTED FOR BREVITY
// REDACTED FOR BREVITY
              
        "incident": [
          {
            "validityPeriod": {
              "from": "2021-02-03T05:56:19Z",
              "until": "2021-02-12T06:11:28Z"
            },
            "text": "trabajos de construcción",
            "type": "roadworks",
            "criticality": 2,
            "firstPoint": 2110,
            "lastPoint": 2148
          }
        ],
        "label": [
          "A-10",
          "N-I"
        ],
        "zone": []
      }
    ],
    "language": "es-es"
  }
}
```

**Edit**

It turned out there is a road allowing trucks, that goes through those waypoints, but as it includes a toll cost, it is necessary to remove the `tollroad:-3` part from the parameter `mode=fastest;truck;tollroad:-3` in order to have the route returned.

Comment: Okay, that's something I missed there.. does that mean that trucks are not allowed to go through that road? I find that strange because I've seen many trucks take that road time and time again... could it be because of the roadworks? Thank you very much again for your time.

Comment: Truck routing is what I am working on right now, but I missed that the Here WeGo route that I posted was by car. I am sorry for that.

Comment: This is because the resulting road probably contains a toll for trucks. If we use `fastest;truck;tollroad:-2`, we can find a route. `-3` is for strict exclusion, while `-2` is what is called a soft exclusion: routing engine will try to exclude tolls as much as possible

Comment: Indeed, there is a toll road in the result, which is why no route is returned when `tollroad:-3` is in the mode parameter.

Comment: Yes there is, I am sorry... I always thought there was no toll there but yesterday I took that road back home and I saw it. Thank you very much for your time Micheal.